# SharePoint 2013 Immediate Alerts timer job not running

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, sharepoint-alerts

We have a Single Development Server for SharePoint 2013.I have set the user alert for one of library in a site. When I check the central administrator site, the Immediate Alerts timer job never ever ran before and when I try to make amanuall run it is not whoing in "running jobs" or in "job history"

I have checked the SMTP settings,Alert enabled over the web application and SharePoint Timer service also running.

Kindly help me on why it is actually not running for me.

Thanks
Kailash

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to troubleshooting the issue.

1.Open SharePoint Management Shell and execute code below:

```
# Get WFE server on which you want to restore the timer service
$server = Get-SPServer -Identity "<name of WFE server>" 
$ts = $server.ServiceInstances | ? { $_.GetType().Name -like "*sptimerservice*" } | Select -First 1
$ts.AllowContentDatabaseJobs = $true
$ts.AllowServiceJobs = $true
$ts.Update()
```

2.Open Central Administration and go to Manage content databases then select content database and select the server specified in the previous step as the Preferred Server for Timer Jobs.

3.Restart SharePoint Timer Service.

If the issue persists, you could try to run the configuration wizard then reboot the server.